# Extracting rows as columns from batched time series table

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series, crosstable

Is it possible to convert table with batched time data series that looks like this:

| id | technology | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | technology 1 | 123 | 2 |
| 2 | technology 2 | 123 | 3 |
| 3 | technology 3 | 123 | 0.5 |
| 4 | technology 1 | 124 | 3 |
| 5 | technology 2 | 124 | 1,2 |
| 6 | technology 3 | 124 | 8 |

to table with particular "technology part" as a dimension (column?), for example this:

| id | technology | time | value | technology 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | technology 1 | 123 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | technology 3 | 123 | 0.5 | 3 |
| 4 | technology 1 | 124 | 3 | 1,2 |
| 5 | technology 3 | 124 | 8 | 1,2 |

The value of "technology 2" needs to be in all rows with the same time mark.

Thanks.

I tried to do this in qliksense with "crosstable" function but I'm not able to get the right result, so maybe it will be possible in native SQL.

Comment: Yes, you can do this; conditional aggregation would be one way. A self-join might be easier though.

Comment: As a side note, it *looks* like your column `value` stores denormalised data; you probably want to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id         INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,technology VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
  ,time       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,value      VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO foo (id,technology,time,value) VALUES
 (1,'technology 1',123,'2')
,(2,'technology 2',123,'3')
,(3,'technology 3',123,'0.5')
,(4,'technology 1',124,'3')
,(5,'technology 2',124,'1,2')
,(6,'technology 3',124,'8');

SELECT t1.id, t1.technology, t1.time, t2.value AS technology2
FROM foo AS t1
LEFT JOIN foo AS t2
ON t1.time = t2.time AND t2.technology = 'technology 2'
WHERE t1.technology != 'technology 2';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it using `MAX` window function, and `CASE` expression to build conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, max(case when technology = 'technology 2' then value end )
          over (partition by time) as 'technology 2'
  FROM mytable AS t1
) AS s
WHERE s.technology != 'technology 2';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0HJXOT_-)